# JPA composite key one to may relationship separate table

Tags: java, database, jpa, spring-data-jpa, relational-database

I am working on mapping a relationship using a composite key, but the composite key is a separate table.

Car Table

```
car Id
car description
car Value
```

SafetyReport Table

```
safetyReport Id
safetyReport Date
safetyReport Value
```

CompositeKey CarSafetyReport Table

```
carid
safetyReportId
```

One To Many: A car will have many safety reports

JPA:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "CarTable")
public class CarEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "CarId", nullable = false)
    private int carId;

    @Column(name = "CarDescription", nullable = false)
    private String carDescription;

    @Column(name = "CarValue", nullable = false)
    private String carDescription;

}

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "SafetyReport")
public class SafetyReportEntity  {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "SafetyReportId", nullable = false)
    private int SafetyReportID;

    @Column(name = "SafetyReportDate", nullable = false)
    private OffsetDataTime date;

    @Column(name = "SafetyReportValue", nullable = false)
    private String safetyReportValue;

}

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "CarSafetyReport")
public class CarSafetyReportEntity implements Serializable  {

    @EmbeddedId
    private CarSafetyReportPk id;

}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Embeddable
public class CarSafetyReportPk implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "CarId", nullable = false)
    private int carId;

    @Column(name = "SafetyReportId", nullable = false)
    private int SafetyReportId;

}
```

I tried

```
public class CarEntity {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "id.carId" )
    private List<CarSafetyReportEntity> carSafetyReportEntity;
}
```

I also tried putting the relationship in the composite key `CarSafetyReportPk` but i got an error for the annotation `@OneToMany` in a composite key.

Comment: What is the purpose of `CarSafetyReport` instead of just directly having a `ManyToMany`?

Comment: the CarSafetyReport table removes the direct relationship from the Car and SafetyReport. then any other entity can use the SafetyReport, by just creating a new table NewEntitySafetyReport without modifying the existing tables.